# Replacing Text in a child under parent DIV through JQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I want to change text of *(Access denied. Please Login or Register.)* to ***"You are not authorized to access"*** in the following code:-

```
<div class="messages error">
<h2 class="element-invisible">Error message</h2>
Access denied. Please Login or Register.
</div>
```

I tried using the following code in on Ready Function, but it isn't working correctly.

```
$("div.messages").text(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        return $(this).text().replace("Access denied. Please Login or Register.", "You are not authorized to access"); 
    });
```

Thanks.

---

Is there anyother way to do that? It gives me the error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined ...
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it isn't working correctly".

Comment: It isn't replacing the text. Basically "not doing" what I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.messages h2")
      .prop('nextSibling')
      .nodeValue = "You are not authorized to access";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZwLKZ/

```
$("div.messages").contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== ''; 
}).get(0).nodeValue = "You are not authorized to access";
```

Comment: Actually, no, it didn't ... It works but with the error shown below.